# Android Studio: How to add a project using relative path?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, mercurial

I want to migrate to Android Studio instead of Eclipse to work on our Android version of our Application. I tried a lot of stuff but i cannot actually add a project reference into my Android Studio Project.

**Details:**

I have a mercurial repository consisting of theses folders:

- Root
- Root/PROJECTA
- Root/PROJECTB

Note that actually, in eclipse, projectB is a project reference of PROJECTA. Then, when i compile, the PROJECTB is compiled and after the PROJECTA. If i made change in any of theses projects, my source control track all the changes.

When migrating to Android Studio, PROJECTB becomes a subfolder in PROJECTA.
So i delete the PROJECTB and try to include it as a reference to PROJECTA but it just does not work. The only way i made it works is to have the PROJECTB being a subfolder under PROJECTA.

But this isn't a solution because we have 20 projects that uses PROJECTB as dependancy and I must be able to add it in each project as a reference.

Does anyone has a solution to that blocking behaviour?

**There is the solutions i have tried yet:**

1- Using gradle files with many different parameters:

include ':PROJECTB'
project(':PROJECTB).projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../PROJECTB)

2- Using many Android Studio importations

3- Asking God to help me

Now I'm asking to you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `PROJECTB` in `PROJECTA` you have to do following:

Modify your `PROJECTA` `settings.gradle` to include `PROJECTB` and define `PROJECTB` path

```
include ':app', ':PROJECTB'
project(':PROJECTB').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../PROJECTB')
```

and then add `PROJECTB` as dependency to your `PROJECTA` `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':PROJECTB')
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working for me right now! But the real thing is the way I migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio that was the source of my problem. I tried first to Migrate ProjectB and after migrate PROJECTA and add the reference to PROJECTB, but it did not work because of grade files i think. So this morning, I migrate the ProjectA and let Android Studio migrate the PROJECTB too. Then, i move the PROJECTB at the same folder level as PROJECTA. Then i use your recommandations in grade file and BOOM! The prject is now available in Android Studio and everything is fine! Thank you!

Comment: FYI: I used Android Studio version 1.0.2

Comment: It's not working. After adding into the project, inside External Libraries under this project's classes.jar it is just showing `MANIFEST.MF`